# Google AppMaker: Fetch a MAX value

Tags: max, google-app-maker

I am not able to fetch a max value from a number field in AppMaker. The field is filled with unique integers from 1 and up. In SQL I would have asked like this:

```sql
SET @tKey = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM GiftCard);
```

In AppMaker I have done the following (with a bit help from other contributors in this forum) until now, and it returns tKey = "NaN":

```javascript
var tKey = google.script.run.MaxID();

function MaxID() {
  var ID_START_FROM = 11000;
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(3000);
  var query = app.models.GiftCard.newQuery();
  query.sorting.ID._descending();
  query.limit = 1;
  var records = query.run();
  var next_id = records.length > 0 ? records[0].ID : ID_START_FROM;
  lock.releaseLock();
  return next_id;
}
```

There is also a maxValue() function in AppMaker. However, it seems not to work in that way I use it. If maxvalue() is better to use, please show :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking in direction of auto incremented fields. The right way to achieve it would be using [Cloud SQL database](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql). MySQL will give you more flexibility with configuring your ids:

```sql
ALTER TABLE GiftCard AUTO_INCREMENT = 11000;
```

In case you strongly want to stick to Drive Tables you can try to fix your script as follow:

```javascript
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(maxId) {
    var tKey = maxId;
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
    // TODO: handle error
  })
  .MaxID();
```

As a side note I would also recommend to set your ID in `onBeforeCreate` model event as an extra security layer instead of passing it to client and reading back since it can be modified by malicious user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). Take into consideration the example below:

```
function getMax() {

  var query = app.models.GiftCard.newQuery();
  var allRecords = query.run();

  allIds = [];
  for( var i=0; i<allRecords.length;i++){
     allIds.push(allRecords[i].ID); 
  }

  var maxId = Math.max.apply(null, allIds);
  return maxId;

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Querying all records from a table can have significant performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for examples! The Math.max returned an undefined value. Since this simple case is a "big" issue, I will solve this in another way. This value is meant as a starting value for a sequence only. An SQL base is better yes!